# OpenCV for Android - Access elements of Mat

Tags: android, opencv

What is the standard way to access and modify individual elements of a Mat in OpenCV4Android?  Also, what is the format of the data for BGR (which is the default, I think) and grayscale?
edit: Let's make this more specific.  mat.get(row, col) returns a double array.  What is in this array?

Comment: have you read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)?

Comment: Of course.  There was no point even referring to it in my initial question because it refers only to the C++ API, which uses pointers, and also because it talks mostly about Mat as a container structure rather than the things you can put in it.

Comment: Well I only know about the C++ API so I can't help you if you are not interested in that.  If you want help from other people, you should try to make your question more specific.  Like you said, Mat is a container.  what mat.get(row,col) returns depends entirely on what you have put in that mat.  BGR may be the default format for certain functions in opencv but Mat is type agnostic.  Usually though images are stored as uchars.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the standard way to access and modify individual elements of a Mat in OpenCV4Android?

A `Mat` is the thing we call a "matrix" in Mathematics - a rectangular array of quantities set out by rows and columns. Those "quantities" represent pixels in the case of an image Mat, (e.g. every element of a matrix can be the *color* of each pixel in an image Mat). From [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#matthebasicimagecontainer) tutorial:

> [image]
>
> in the above image you can see that the mirror of the car is nothing
>   more than a matrix containing all the intensity values of the pixel
>   points.

So how would you go about iterating through a matrix? How about this:

```
for (int row=0; row<mat.rows(); row++) {
  for (int col=0; col<mat.cols(); col++ ) {
    //...do what you want.. 
    //e.g. get the value of the 3rd element of 2nd row 
    //by mat.get(2,3);
  }
}
```

> What is the standard way to access and modify individual elements of a Mat in OpenCV4Android?

You get the value of an element of `Mat` by using its function `get(x)(y)`, where `x` is the first coordinate (row number) and `y` is the second coordinate (column number) of the element. For example to get the 4th element of the 7th row of a `BGR` image `Mat` named `bgrImageMat`, use the `get` method of `Mat` to get an array of type `double`, which will have a size of `3`, each array element representing each of the `Blue`, `Green`, and `Red` channels of the `BGR` image format.

```
double [] bgrColor = bgrImageMat.get();
```

> Also, what is the format of the data for BGR (which is the default, I think) and grayscale? edit: Let's make this more specific. mat.get(row, col) returns a double array. What is in this array?

You can read about BGR color format and grayscale from the web. e.g. [BGR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGR) and [Grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale).

In short, BGR color format has 3 channels: `Blue`, `Green` and `Red`. So the `double` array returned by `mat.get(row, col)`, when `mat` is a `BGR` image, is an array of size 3, and each of its elements contains the values of each of the `Blue`, `green` and `red` channels respectively.

Likewise, Grayscale format is a 1 channel color format, so the `double` returned will have a size of 1.

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to access some pixels do it by using **double[] get(int row, int col)** and writing using **put(int row, int col, double... data)**. If you are thinking in accessing the whole image or iterate the data of the image in a loop the best thing you should do is copy the Mat data into a Java primitive data type. When you're done with the data operations just copy the data back into a Mat structure.

Images use **CV_8U**, if you have a grayscale image it will use **CV_8UC1** if you have a RGB image it will use a Mat of **CV_8UC3** (3 channels of CV_8U). **CV_8U** is the equivalent of byte in java. :)

I can give you and example of a method I use in Java (Android platform) to *binarize* a grayscale image:

```
private Mat featuresVectorBinarization(Mat fv){

    int size = (int) fv.total() * fv.channels();
    double[] buff = new double[size];
    fv.get(0, 0, buff);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buff[i] = (buff[i] >= 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    Mat bv = new Mat(fv.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
    bv.put(0, 0, buff);
    return bv;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please check this question almost similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204124/how-to-iterate-in-opencv4android

Comment: @AshokVarma Sorry but never used OpenCV with the C++ Interface so I don't even know what the MatIterator is. But if the Iterator is a way to cycle through the Image Mat, you can achieve the same with the piece of code I  have above. Use the get method of the Mat to serialize your Mat into a Buffer (buff in the above code) and then with a cycle do the operations you want.

At the end create a target Mat (the result) and deserialize with put.
I don't know if this helps but it is basically what the code above is doing, in this case I was transforming the image to black and white.

Comment: What is the third argument of `Mat.get()`? This method is not described in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html). :s

Comment: @Solace The third argument of Mat.get() is the array you want to store the values to, you will see that such a function does not return any pixel values while the function get() with only 2 arguments returns the double array as mentioned in this answer. I agree, the documentation is bad.

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand from learning about OpenCV Mat object is that Mat is object that can represent any image of W x H pixels.

Now lets say you want to access center pixel of your image then

X = W/2
Y = H/2

Then you can access pixel data as follows 
double[] data = matObject.get(x,y);

Now what does data represent and what is size of data array.That depends on image type.
if image is grayscale then data.length = 1 , since there is one channel only , and data[0] represents color value of that pixel ie. 0(black) - 255(white)

if image is color image then data.length = 4(rgba) , since there are four channels , and data[0-n] represent color value of that pixel