# What Default Type Mat Image OpenCV4Android?

Tags: java, image, opencv

```
ImageManipulationsActivity.VIEW_MODE_BINARY:
capture.retrieve(mRgba, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);

Mat binary = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba,binary, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 4);

int size = (int) binary.total() * binary.channels();
double[] buff = new double[size];
binary.get(0, 0, buff);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    buff[i] = (buff[i] >= 0) ? 1 : 0;
}

Mat bv = new Mat(binary.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
bv.put(0, 0, buff);

Imgproc.cvtColor(binary, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);

break;
```

Above code is used for binarize gray image in opencv4android, but until know that's not work for me, i copy above code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12493075/1593269), in above code, i try :

1. Retrive Mat Image using : capture.retrieve
2. Convert Image to Grayscale using Imgproc.cvtColor
3. Binarize using Java Primitive Array like above code
4. Then Convert back from gray to rgba
5. Show result using Bitmap bmp

If you have something to suggest, please tell me. I don't know what i wrong from above code, it's no error, but when i install the app and run it, it always forceclose.

this is logcat from app :

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible: 0 at org.opencv.core.Mat.get(Mat.java:2042) at org.opencv.samples.imagemanipulations.ImageManipulationsView.processFrame(ImageM‌​anipulationsView.java:158) at org.opencv.samples.imagemanipulations.SampleCvViewBase.run(SampleCvViewBase.java‌​:99) at org.opencv.samples.imagemanipulations.ImageManipulationsView.run(ImageManipulati‌​onsView.java:195) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: there's a threshold() function in c++, in java as well, i suppose.

Comment: The corresponding Java primitive array type depends on the Mat type:
CV_8U and CV_8S -> byte[],
CV_16U and CV_16S -> short[],
CV_32S -> int[],
CV_32F -> float[],
CV_64F-> double[].
but how can i know which type of my MAT image that i was used

Comment: any body can help me pleaseee,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Default Type of Mat is CV_8UC1 whether single channels or 3 channels (BGR) [-Basic Structure OpenCV-](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html)