# get(row, col, double[]) Opencv Android

Tags: android, opencv

I just tried to use a solution found on this website, to access data from my mat from OpenCv, in an Android app.

```
int size = (int) this.getMyMat().total() * this.getMyMat().channels();
double[] buff = new double[size];
this.getMyMat().get(0, 0, buff);
```

The 3rd line crashes my app, and I get this error :
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible: 0

I don't known why, it's just a copy/past from here : [OpenCV for Android - Access elements of Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394364/opencv-for-android-access-elements-of-mat)

Here a copy/paste from the get method of OpenCV :

```
public int get(int row, int col, double[] data) {
    int t = type();
    if (data == null || data.length % CvType.channels(t) != 0)
        throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Provided data element number (" +
                        (data == null ? 0 : data.length) +
                        ") should be multiple of the Mat channels count (" +
                        CvType.channels(t) + ")");
    if (CvType.depth(t) == CvType.CV_64F) {
        return nGetD(nativeObj, row, col, data.length, data);
    }
    throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("Mat data type is not compatible: " + t);
}
```

Forgot to precise that my this.getMyMat() is obtained from :

```
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(this.getMyGrayMat(), dst, max_BINARY_value, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, threshold_type, 27, 3);
```

So this a pure black and white mat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as I said at the end of my question, my mat is in black and white.

So I don't need to use

```
double[] buff = new double[size];
```

but

```
byte[] buff = new byte[size];
```